# I have passwords hashed into 512 bits, how to store them in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, binary-data

I have passwords hashed into 512 bits, how to store them in MySQL?

Initially I wanted **`BINARY(512)`**

However binary has fixed length 255.

I know I can use **`VARBINARY(512)`**

But since my data is "fixed" and not variable-length, i do not think this is the best solution and am looking for a better alternative.

From the page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html:

> In some cases, it may be desirable to
>   store binary data such as media files
>   in `BLOB` or `TEXT` columns. You may find
>   MySQL's string handling functions
>   useful for working with such data.

So does that mean that there is another way to store binary data other than `BLOB`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 512-bit is 64-byte, you can use `BINARY(64)` for that purpose. Please note that length for `BINARY()` type is measured by bytes and not bits.

From [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html):

> The BINARY and VARBINARY types are
>   similar to CHAR and VARCHAR, except
>   that they contain binary strings
>   rather than nonbinary strings. That
>   is, **they contain byte strings** rather
>   than character strings.

Answer (score 2):

512 bits is 64 bytes so `BINARY(64)` should do

Answer (score 1):

512 bits is just 64 bytes. `CHAR`(`BINARY`) can hold up to 255.

Comment: i am aware that char can hold up to 255. But isn't it true that since my data is binary data, i should be storing it as "binary" so that inserts and lookups will generally be faster?

Comment: @Yong: Premature optimization is the root of all evil (Donald Knuth). In a given conversation the user will access the password only once (during login).

Comment: `BINARY` and `CHAR` have the same restrictions and very similar; Initially, I typed `CHAR` just because it has fewer letters than word `BINARY` (the answer is already updated).

Comment: Not all valid binary values are valid in all character encodings -- imagine UTF-8, for instance. In this case I would use the type (`BINARY`) "free" of dealing with such issues that more adequately describes the usage.

Comment: @home you are applying the wrong concept here. we are talking about databases. and yes for my case it's nothing premature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd convert to HEX string and then store in VARCHAR.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Makes hand querying a little nicer, but doesn't really help programmatic access -- where it might even make things more complicated -- and "wastes space" ;-)

Comment: @pst you can query using where binary_field = 0xHEX representaion, or use HEX() and UNHEX() functions. Recent versions of phpMyAdmin will show hex representation of content of binary fields